# Install nginx 1.8 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, nginx

I'm trying to install nginx 1.8 on Centos 7. I tried the following steps:

1. Install nginx repo from http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html

   ```
   wget http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/noarch/RPMS/nginx-release-centos-7-0.el7.ngx.noarch.rpm
   rpm -ivh nginx-release-centos-7-0.el7.ngx.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Install Nginx

   ```
   yum install nginx
   ```
3. Start Nginx:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start nginx
   ```

But nothing happens; nginx doesn't start. The exact same steps work on Centos 6 without a problem.

Here is the output of `systemctl status  nginx`:

```
nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2015-08-06 14:30:51 UTC; 21s ago
  Process: 29865 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 29776 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 06 13:31:12 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Aug 06 13:31:12 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Aug 06 13:31:30 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Aug 06 13:31:54 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Aug 06 13:31:57 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Aug 06 13:32:04 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Aug 06 14:30:20 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Aug 06 14:30:51 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Stopping The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Aug 06 14:30:51 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Stopped The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Aug 06 14:30:56 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Stopped The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: do, `tail -f -n0 /var/log/messages` on your centos machine and then do, `systemctl start nginx`. systemctl logs the service start error messages here...

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/install-nginx-in-centos-7/

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands below

```
hostnamectl
hostnamectl set-hostname servername.domain.com
hostnamectl
systemctl restart sshd.service

rpm -Uvh http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/noarch/RPMS/nginx-release-centos-7-0.el7.ngx.noarch.rpm

yum install nginx
systemctl enable nginx.service
systemctl start nginx.service

systemctl stop httpd.service  or systemctl disable httpd
yum remove httpd
systemctl disable httpd.service

systemctl enable nginx.service
systemctl start nginx.service

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
```

http://your_server_IP_address/

Comment: this is not answering the question nor solving the described problem

Comment: There are a few things I'm not sure why they're included like restarting the ssh service, and this may not solve the problem, but it is actually a possible solution to the vague question in my opinion.